# how to manage Transaction-manager and sessionFactory with Multitenance with multi dataSource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, multi-tenant

In my web application i am using `Spring3, hibernate3` with Transaction manager through annotation till now this application have `single dataSource` so single `sessionFactory`.

Now as this is moving to *Multitenant* which have **Seperate** DB for seprate tenant. Presentaly i am manageing all tenant information through **ThreadLocal** per request which have db credential as well as dataSource.

But main problem came when need to support **Transaction Manager** for all this dynamically selected dataSource.

So below are my questions:

```
 1. How to update Transaction Manager as per request when dataSource changes ?
 2. If I also maintain SessionFactory for each tenant as manageing dataSource but how to update Transaction Manager for each sessionFactory ?
```

**Note: I can NOT define these dataSources in xml file, because there is no-predefined tenants.**

> Please help me ... :( ...

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Bean(name="transactionManager1")
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory1){
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager1 = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager1;     
    }


    @Bean(name="transactionManager2")
    public HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory2){
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager2 = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager2;     
    }



    <aop:config>
    <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* ....)" advice-ref="transactionAdvice1"/>
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="transactionAdvice1" transaction-manager="transactionManager1">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method ..../>                       
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

    <aop:config>
    <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* ....)" advice-ref="transactionAdvice2"/>
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="transactionAdvice1" transaction-manager="transactionManager2">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method ..../>                       
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Comment: Hey Nandkumar, as i already told that i can not go with XML based configuration for transaction manager because I don't know for how many dataSource i have to do this.

What i think (don't know right or wrong) that there will be only **one transaction-manager configured in XMl**. and for that there will dynamic updation of dataSource (as required) on each new request.

Is that type of things is possible with spring.